# Call method only on change in visible windows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to call a method every time there is a visible change in the currently viewable system windows.  For example, I'm getting the full visible window list with:

```
CFArrayRef openWindows =(CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID));
```

This will return an array such as:

```
{
        kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
        kCGWindowBounds =         {
            Height = 713;
            Width = 1279;
            X = 1;
            Y = 22;
        };
        kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
        kCGWindowLayer = 0;
        kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 3772468;
        kCGWindowName = "Stack Overflow";
        kCGWindowNumber = 7138;
        kCGWindowOwnerName = "Google Chrome";
        kCGWindowOwnerPID = 49972;
        kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
        kCGWindowStoreType = 2;
    }
```

Due to the kCGWindowMemoryUsage value constantly changing, I cannot simply compare a previously stored CFArrayRef with the current one.

Comment: Can't you just write your own comparison function, which compares only selected elements of the info?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I'm trying to keep CPU usage down as much as possible, and the for loop running the comparison basically uses as much CPU as working with out the comparison in the first place.  I'm basically looping over this function several times a second, hence the CPU usage.

Comment: Since you're showing a dictionary of window properties, I assumed there is a call to `CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray` that you didn't show. Then, since you said you "cannot simply compare a previously stored CFArrayRef", I assumed you were calling `CFEqual()` on the arrays.  What I meant was, just do your own implementation of CFEqual() which compares only certain entries in each dictionary -- it should actually be faster than CFEqual, since it's comparing fewer things.  CFEqual probably compares every element of each dictionary by calling `CFEqual(this string, that string)`.